# Does PgBouncer create a separate pool for every database config entry?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, max-connections, pgbouncer

If I set up a pgbouncer.ini config file with several database entries, does pgBouncer create a separate pool for each one?  I would think so, but have not been able to confirm this.

For example, with something like this:

```
[databases]
db1 = ...
db2 = ...

[pgbouncer]

.
.
.
max_client_conn = 480

default_pool_size = 250
```

Would I have a default pool of 250 **for each DB** and a max of 480, or a **total** of 250 default and max of 480 connections that are **shared between both?**

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, pgbouncer creates a separate pool for each database. You really don't want a pool size as big as 250 in a scenario like this - because that is 250 connections from pgbouncer to the postgres server *for each database*.

The max of 480 is the total number of connections from clients into pgbouncer, regardless of which database they go into.

Comment: Would you happen to know when the pool of 250 user connections is created? It can't be on pgbouncer startup as the userid/pwd may not be known yet... Would the 250 connections be created when the first connection from a client is made?

Comment: > pgbouncer creates a separate pool for each database

I think it is not quite right.
pgbouncer creates separate pools per db per user.
N users, M databases can make N*M separate pools if all users connect to all databases.

Answer (score 4):

> Would I have a default pool of 250 for each DB and a max of 480, or a
>   total of 250 default and max of 480 connections that are shared
>   between both?

You will have **one pool per DB per user** (or role) of you omit specifying user in db1 or db2 lines inside [databases] section. 
Though you can enforce connecting with some predefined user if you want.

You kind of misunderstood what `max_client_conn` is . It is the "lightweight" connections limit. The max connections made TO pgbouncer not to database server.